# React Package with Webpack - Only a ReactOwner can have refs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, package

I'm creating a react package called Supernova. So, in other project that i use this package (with npm link) this error is showing in the console:

> Only a ReactOwner can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a
>   component that was not created inside a component's `render` method,
>   or you have multiple copies of React loaded

This is my Supernova webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',

  output: {
    library: 'Supernova',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: __dirname + '/build',
    filename: 'index.js',
  },

  externals: [
    {
      react: {
        root: 'React',
        commonjs2: 'react',
        commonjs: 'react',
        amd: 'react'
      }
    }
  ],

  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.jsx?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel' },
      {
        test:   /\.(scss|sass|css)$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&name=fonts/[hash].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },

  node: {
    Buffer: false
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("[name].css"),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
    })
  ]
}
```

And my component method render is:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="sn-search-box">
        {this.renderSelecteds()}

        <input
          ref="input"
          type="text"
          className="sn-search-box__input"
          placeholder={this.props.label} autoComplete="off"
          onFocus={this.handleInputFocus.bind(this)}
          onBlur={this.handleInputBlur.bind(this)}/>

        <span className="sn-search-box__input--icon"></span>

        {this.state.hasFocus ? this.renderResults() : null}
        {this.renderHelpMessage()}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

My Supernova package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "material-design-icons": "^2.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.3.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^13.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "jest-cli": "*",
    "node-sass": "^3.8.0",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "~15.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.14",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: string refs are deprecated, trying using the function and see if that fixes anything https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: It works! Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused because of loading **Multiple copies of React** in a same project. This happens when your package has it own copy of React and you project which consumes your package has another.

This happen when you make React as a `dependency` in your `package`(supernova). You need to make React as a `peerDependency`. By doing this, your package will consume React from your project. If no React is found in the project, npm will throw an error/warning when you do `npm i supernova`.

- [npm peerDependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies)

Comment: I have put react and react-dom as peerDepedencies but after I ran webpack in Supernova and tested it in another project the error continues.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling supernova from your project.

Comment: This solution works: "string refs are deprecated, trying using the function and see if that fixes anything facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html " but how can i debug this?

Comment: After installing supernova go to super nova under your project's node_modules and check i react is found inside supernova's node_modules

Comment: Yes, React is in supernova's node_modules.

Comment: @BrunoQuaresma That's the issue. React shouldn't be there. Add react only in peer dependency.